# XSLT using regex pattern

Tags: regex, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a requirements to get the value based on a priority @schemeNames. Get the value of ID if the @schemeName='TaxNumber' is present, else if @schemeName='PassportNumber', else if @schemeName is no value. After getting the value, it needs to check or ignore the 1st 2 characters if it is Alpha. Also, I need to consider the spaces between words in @schemeName. If for example, the value of my @schemeName is 'Tax Number' or 'taxnumber' it is valid. But if the value is like this, 't axNum Ber', it should not validate this value.

Here is my XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <Result>
        <xsl:for-each select="/Record/Data/ID">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="matches(lower-case(.[@schemeName]),'^tax\s+number')">
                    <xsl:if test="matches(substring(.,1,2),'^[a-zA-Z]+$')">
                        <xsl:value-of select="substring(.,3)"/>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="matches(lower-case(.[@schemeName]),'^passport\s+number')">
                    <xsl:if test="matches(substring(.,1,2),'^[a-zA-Z]+$')">
                        <xsl:value-of select="substring(.,3)"/>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test=".[@schemeName='']">
                    <xsl:if test="matches(substring(.,1,2),'^[a-zA-Z]+$')">
                        <xsl:value-of select="substring(.,3)"/>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Result>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

INPUT:

```
<Record>
    <Data>
    <ID schemeName="TaxNumber">PT123457</ID>
    <ID schemeName="PassportNumber">PT098732</ID>
    <ID schemeName="LicenseNumber">PT445423</ID>
    <ID schemeName="">PT7566435</ID>
</Data>
</Record>
```

GENERATED OUTPUT:

```
<Result>7566435</Result>
```

The output generated is coming from the @schemeName that is null. It should be coming from the TaxNumber since it is present. There's something wrong in my condition when checking the @schemeNames.

I am using XSLT v2.0. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about setting your priorities in variables? Something like:

```
    <xsl:variable name="prio1" select="ID[matches(lower-case(@schemeName),'^tax\s?number')]"/>
    <xsl:variable name="prio1_value">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="matches($prio1, '^[A-z]{2}.*$')">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring($prio1,3)"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$prio1"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="prio2" select="ID[matches(lower-case(@schemeName),'^passport\s?number')]"/>
    <xsl:variable name="prio2_value">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="matches($prio2, '^[A-z]{2}.*$')">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring($prio2,3)"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$prio2"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="prio3" select="ID[@schemeName='']"/>
    <xsl:variable name="prio3_value">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="matches($prio3, '^[A-z]{2}.*$')">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring($prio3,3)"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$prio3"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
```

**Note:** I have changed `\s+` to `\s?` to make the space optional.

Also, you can use the `if-then-else` construct in xslt 2.0. The final code is below:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>


    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Record/Data"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Data">
    <xsl:variable name="prio1" select="ID[matches(lower-case(@schemeName),'^tax\s?number')]"/>
    <xsl:variable name="prio1_value">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="matches($prio1, '^[A-z]{2}.*$')">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring($prio1,3)"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$prio1"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="prio2" select="ID[matches(lower-case(@schemeName),'^passport\s?number')]"/>
    <xsl:variable name="prio2_value">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="matches($prio2, '^[A-z]{2}.*$')">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring($prio2,3)"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$prio2"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="prio3" select="ID[@schemeName='']"/>
    <xsl:variable name="prio3_value">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="matches($prio3, '^[A-z]{2}.*$')">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring($prio3,3)"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$prio3"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>

    <Result>
        <xsl:value-of select="if ($prio1) then ($prio1_value) else 
        if ($prio2) then ($prio2_value) else
        if ($prio3) then ($prio3_value) else 0"/>
    </Result>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It did worked, but the only problem is I only need to check if the 1st 2 characters are alpha. I doesn't matter if there are letters in the other position.

Comment: If it's a valid schemeName, and if the first 2 letters are not alpha, then you have no output?

Comment: If it's a valid schemeName, and if the first 2 letters are not alpha, then get the value as is.